# hazelcast cluster 2 nodes same machine

Tags: hazelcast

I'm developing an application broken into multiple micro-services. for now, I have only 1 server, and 3 micro-services running on it, each in a different jvm-process.

I would like to configure them in a hazelcast cluster so I could use the ReplicatedMap to share some information across the processes.

my question is: how do I configure the hazelcast xml so my 3 processes can join the cluster on the same machine, and share a ReplicatedMap?

is what I want possible?
it looks like a cluster can only be mounted across multiple servers.

note: my server is an AWS EC2 server, and so I want to avoid using multicast.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a best use-case of Hazelcast. You can make use of the IMap, the distributed map for sharing the data across the nodes.
Just add the below configuration to the join module of your Hazelcast.xml and start your instances. They will discover each other themselves and form a cluster.

```
<join>
  <multicast enabled="false">
  </multicast>
  <tcp-ip enabled="false">
  </tcp-ip>
  <aws enabled="true">
    <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
    <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
    <iam-role>s3access</iam-role>
    <region>us-west-1</region>
    <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
    <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
    <tag-key>type</tag-key>
    <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
  </aws>
</join>
```

The tag-key & tag-value properties are what would be responsible for joining together and forming the cluster.